# What all does founder-status entail?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

If you activate a paid subscription to Elite before November 13, 2011, you gain "founder status".  What all does this entail?  Does it affect the game in any way (even just vanity wise)?  Or does it only affect interactions with the Elite service?

Answer (score 2):

From [Activision](http://www.callofduty.com/elite/whats-included) (you have to scroll to the bottom and click on BECOME A CALL OF DUTY® ELITE FOUNDER), becoming a founder, awards you with the following (all listed as exclusive) items:

- Founder Weapon Camo
- Clan XP Boost - Level Up Your Clan Even Faster
- Founder In-Game Player Title
- Founder In-Game Emblem
- Private Group
- Founder Call of Duty® ELITE Profile Skin
- Competitions & Prizes

There is no mention of future iterations and what that may affect.